# Highcharts exporting module not working in android device

Tags: android, highcharts

The graph generated from Highcharts is perfectly visible on both Chrome (Windows) and Webview (Android). However, when I click on "Download PNG image" or "Download JPEG image" or "Download PDF document", nothing happens. Not even a call to the default browser. But this feature works on Chrome (Windows).

Currently, I have placed the charts in the assets folder of my application. I am using android 4.4.2 on Nexus 4 for testing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How we can reproduce this issue?